# Django form search

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-views

I am making a search form in django, and I am struggling with processing the form in my view.

My code:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Name", max_length=64, required=False)
    ...
    <a few other fields>


def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            qdict = { 'name': name}
            q_objs = [Q(**{qdict[k]: form.cleaned_data[k]}) for k in qdict.keys() if form.cleaned_data.get(k, None)]
            search_results = Group.objects.select_related().filter(*q_objs)
            response = {'success' : search_results}
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response, ensure_ascii=False), mimetype='application/javascript')
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
    return render_to_response("main/search.html", {'form': form},
      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I get this error:
Cannot resolve keyword u'NAME' into field. Choices are: date_submitted, id, name, parameters.

I realized that this field is in unicode and tried converting it with str(...) or with encode('ascii',...), but it still gives me the same error. I am new to django, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find your error code replace this code:

```
name = form.cleaned_data['name']
qdict = { 'name': name}
q_objs = [Q(**{qdict[k]: form.cleaned_data[k]}) for k in qdict.keys() if form.cleaned_data.get(k, None)]
search_results = Group.objects.select_related().filter(*q_objs)
```

By this one:

```
q=None
for k,v in form.cleaned_data.items():
  if q:
    q &= Q( k = v )
  else:
    q = Q( k = v )
search_results = Group.objects.select_related().filter( q )
```

But, to have really control over your query, you need to write condition by condition:

```
qs = []

name = form.cleaned_data['name']
if name:
  q_name = Q( name__contains = name )
  qs.append(q_name)

fromDate = form.cleaned_data['fromDate']
if fromDate:
  q_from = Q( date__gte = fromDate )
  qs.append(q_from)

toDate = form.cleaned_data['toDate']
if toDate:
  q_toDate = Q( date__gte = toDate )
  qs.append(q_toDate)

q=None
for x in qs:
  if q:
    q &= x
  else:
    q = x

search_results = Group.objects.select_related().filter(q)
```

Answer (score 0):

It complains about the (uppercase) `NAME` field, and judging by the error message's format, it is the query that triggers it. I can't really tell from your code, but at some point I think you execute the equivalent of the following:

```
Group.objects.filter(NAME='some_value')
```

If the Group model (which you didn't post, so this is an educated guess) contains a lowercase `name` field, the above query will generate the error you posted as it tries to access the uppercase `NAME` field.

So I guess it boils down to: what does the final query look like? For getting information on that, danihp's comment already provided a good breakdown for how to determine this.